# Limit of ratio of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Suppose that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)/n = a>0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{x\to 0} (1-f(x))/n = b>0$. Then
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{1-f(x)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\left( f(x)/n \right)}{\left( (1-f(x))/n \right)}=\frac{a}{b}.$$
Is it true that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = \frac{a}{b}\lim_{x\to 0}(1-f(x))\implies \lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = \frac{a}{a+b}$$
or does this assume that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=a$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}(1-f(x))=b$ which need not be true? How may one compute $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$?

Edit:
Now that I think of it, one could express
$$\frac{f(x)}{1-f(x)}=\frac{a}{b}+o(1)\implies f(x) = \frac{\frac{a}{b}+o(1)}{1+\frac{a}{b}+o(1)}\to \frac{a}{a+b}$$
as $x\to 0$ correct?

Comment: I would start the observation with the following: Let me write $c_n := \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{n}$ and $d_n :=  \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{1-f(x)}{n}$. If $c_n \to a > 0$ and $d_n \to b > 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then $c_n + d_n \to a+b$. But $c_n + d_n = \frac{1}{n}$, so $a=-b$. This cannot be as both $a.b > 0$.

Comment: Thanks @MatyMangoo for your comment. This is really helpful. What would happen if one were to replace $f(x)$ with a function $g(x,\omega)$ with the same convergence conditions mentioned occurring for almost every $\omega$. Would your result still stand out of curiosity?

Comment: It depends on what $g(x,\omega)$ does. You would need a (convergence) condition on what happens for the $\omega$ that do not match with the convergence condition as given for $f(x)$.